# Can anyone tell me what this device is? This car is a 2008 Honda Crv Ex

Tags: identify-this

This is located under the far back passenger side window.[image]

Comment: My guess is a GPS unit for an aftermarket camera or other device

Comment: You've said very little about it. What observations can you make about it? At the nearest corner it looks like a slider conrol, with marking. What is behind the 3 slots?

Comment: On closer observation, it has a volume slider and what appears to be a sound on\off button. So GPS is wrong.

Comment: It looks like it's stuck to the interior with Velcro or an adhesive strip. Rock it gently until it loosens or pops off, then find identifying info on the back or inside if it has a battery compartment.

Comment: Looks like an old pager, they were still widely used in 2008...